# Chrome extension not accessing target page DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

After reviewing the suggested responses, I was not able to resolve the following issue:

My javascript is not accessing the page DOM, but it is running.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Clicky",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": { "scripts": ["jquery.js", "clickclickboom.js"] },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
  "name": "Find all links",
  "icons": ["icon.jpg"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

clickclickboom.js

```
alert("script runs");
function clicky() {
    alert ("clicky got called");
    jQuery(".testClass").find("a");
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    null, {code: clicky()});
});
```

Both alerts pop up but when I debug, I see the extension accessing the background.html DOM but not the targeted pages' DOM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: shouldn't you be using [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)?

Answer (score 0):

In your `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`, the `code` property must be a string containing the code.

What's happening currently with your code is: `clicky()` is executed, which returns `undefined`, which basically is making your executeScript a no-operation call...

One thing you can do is use `clicky.toString()` though I don't personally recommend it! In this case, the `alert ("clicky got called")` may work (if you are lucky). The next line will not work because jQuery is not defined in the content script. Your inclusion of jquery is limited to background page.

From your code, it seems you are not really familiar with chrome extension's architecture, so I suggest you start with http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html